# Stop lightdm/x hanging pi on boot - boot to CLI only

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

I've got an issue with booting, and when the system tries to start x, it hangs and only a cursor is displayed. It is not possible to switch to a command prompt or SSH in at this stage.

Is it possible to change something in the config.txt to boot only into CLI so I can investigate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a number of people have reported this problem recently after relatively innocuous sounding configuration changes or installing software.  I can't diagnose it for it you, however...

> Is it possible to change something in the config.txt to boot only into CLI

Presuming you are using Raspbian **jessie,** there should be something you can add to `cmdline.txt`.  You can override the default target of [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) to use a non-graphical target:

```
 systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Again, that's `cmdline.txt`, not `config.txt`.  And very important: that file should contain **one line**.  No more.  It can be quite long and you should add that to the end separated from the previous parameters by a space.

There are [some other possibilities here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#Boot_Kernel_Command_Line) but try that one first.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked - now I just need to figure out what's wrong with the GUI!